# How to use the "Guessed User name" in tomcat manager in a wicket application?

Tags: java, session, tomcat, wicket

In Tomcat Manager on the Page "Sessions Administration", there is a column **Guessed User name**. How can i set this column from within my Wicket Session?

Note: I have successfully overridden `AuthenticatedWebSession.toString()` and this value is shown on the sessin details page.

I have tried to set `AuthenticatedWebSession.userName` as recommended [here](http://old.nabble.com/How-does-the-Tomcat-Manager-guess-at-%22user-name%22--td23370836.html).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Please mind that Wicket session is a different beast than actual servlet session. Creating a "userName" property in wicket session will not work.

You need to access the raw HttpServletRequest from wicket to set the value properly: [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/raw-httpservletrequest.html) is how you do it.

Add this code to your WebPages:

```
HttpServletRequest request = getWebRequestCycle().getWebRequest().getHttpServletRequest();
request.getSession().setAttribute("userName", userName);
```

Comment: There is also a column in Tomcat Manager Guessed Locale, maybe you know how to set it also?

Comment: @zygimantus, for locale, the manager tries the following attribute names: "org.apache.struts.action.LOCALE", "org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE", "javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.locale", "Locale", "java.util.Locale". See https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/200905.mbox/%3C0AAE5AB84B013E45A7B61CB66943C17228613EA2A8@USEA-EXCH7.na.uis.unisys.com%3E

Comment: Is there any option to update Guessed Locale in apache server 9.0

Answer (score 1):

You can create any Java bean and add it to session like this, 
session.setAttribute("user", user);
Tomcat will find the bean and whatever prints in toString will show up.
[see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHOPG.png)